# Abstracting Identity 2.0 to domain model layer

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, onion-architecture

I'm trying to implement Identity 2.0 in my ASP.NET MVC 5 solution that abides the onion architecture.

I have an `ApplicationUser` in my core.

```
namespace Core.DomainModel
{
    public class ApplicationUser {...}
}
```

In my Data Access Layer I'm using Entity Framework 6.1 and my context derives from `IdentityDbContext` and herein lies the problem. `ApplicationUser` needs to derive from `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUser`

```
namespace Infrastructure.DAL
{
    public class TestContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser> {...}
}
```

My domain model shouldn't reference `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework` that would go against the idea of the onion.

What's a good solution?

Comment: It doesn't look fun: http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/a-sample-of-onion-architecture-with-asp-net-identity

Comment: I found that solution as well but he puts his ORM inside the Domain Model layer it seems, which is wrong :(

Comment: Hold on... I might have been too quick to judge that solution. Ye I misunderstood what he was doing do to the almost identical class names. He's using the adapter pattern to avoid the reference in his domain model, I believe.

Comment: A possible duplicate of this (or other way around not sure)... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25266167/web-api-2-with-owin-oauth-bearer-tokens/25266463#25266463 . This should help.

Answer (score 3):

Yep, this is the big problem with the Identity framework which I have found no good solution yet.

I contemplated adding EF to my domain project, but decided against it in one project: domain models are not aware about `ApplicationUser`, only using `Id` for the current user which they get from

```
ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Claims
    .FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)
    .Value
```

In that project I kept all Identity code in Web and Data projects.

In my other project I have added Identity and EF all over the place, including Domain project. And guess what? nothing bad happened.

I also have looked on solutions like already provided [link](http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/a-sample-of-onion-architecture-with-asp-net-identity) to Imran Baloch' blog. It looked like a lot of work to me to gain no customer value.

Just to repeat myself, there is no good solution to separate EF from Identity without rewriting a pile of code (don't like it). So either add EF to your Domain project (don't like it) or keep your Identity code in Web/Data project (sometimes not possible, so I also don't like it).

Sorry to say, but this is a low-level limitation of .Net.

Answer (score 2):

You can inherit IUser from the Core namespace and the usermanager will be happy. You will need to replace the IUserStore with your own implementation. Then initializer the user manager something like:

```
new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new YourNameSpace.UserStore<YourApplicationUser>()))
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying to use the Onion pattern. In its foundations that you will always build dependencies.

Thrive for single responsibility of your models you are creating. You can do easily this by trying to follow Domain Driven Design properly by implementing individual models per layer:

- BusinessLogic.Models.ApplicationUser
- Presentiation.Models.ApplicationUser
- DAL.Models.ApplicationUser

Note that all of those models are different classes even if they have 100% same properties (although it is never 100%). The drawback is that you may need to map from one model to another, but if you are trully aim for clean, modular and extensible architecture - that is the way. 
Hint you can use [Automapper](http://automapper.org/) (or [ExpressMapper](http://www.expressmapper.org/)) to avoid code needed for mapping.